# How to find variable g in this code?

Tags: java, paintcomponent

How to find variable g in this code? I would like to draw line using fillRect from paintComponent.
Please help.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.String.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;

class Test extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x1;
        String x2;
        String y1;
        String y2;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Podaj pierwsza wspolrzedna pierwszego punktu: ");
        x1 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Podaj druga wspolrzedna pierwszego punktu: ");
        x2 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Podaj pierwsza wspolrzedna drugiego punktu: ");
        y1 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Podaj druga wspolrzedna drugiego punktu: ");
        y2 = sc.nextLine();

        Test nowy = new Test();
        DDA2 dda2 = new DDA2();
        dda2.licz(x1, x2, y1, y2);

        JFrame ramka = new JFrame();
        ramka.setSize(300,300);
        ramka.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ramka.getContentPane().add(new Test());
        ramka.setVisible(true);

    }


}



class DDA2 {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
    }



    public void licz(String xx1, String xx2, String yy1, String yy2){
        double dxx1 = Double.parseDouble(xx1);
        double dxx2 = Double.parseDouble(xx2);
        double dyy1 = Double.parseDouble(yy1);
        double dyy2 = Double.parseDouble(yy2);
        double dx = dxx2 - dxx1;
        double dy = dyy2 - dyy1;

        if (Math.abs(dx) >= Math.abs(dy))
        {
            double m = Math.abs(dx);
            System.out.println("DX" + m);
        }
        else
        {
            // ALGORYTYM PRZYROSTOWY
            double m = Math.abs(dy);
            //System.out.println("DY" + m);
            double x = dxx1;
            double y = dyy1;
            for (int i=1; i <= m; i++)
            {
                x = x + dx/m;
                y = y + dy/m;
                g.fillRect((int) x, (int) y, 1, 1);
            }
        }   

    System.out.println("Wspolrzednie punktu pierwszego to: " + "(" + dxx1 + "; " + dxx2 +")");
    System.out.println("Wspolrzednie punktu drugiego to: " + "(" + dyy1 + "; " + dyy2 + ")");
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no variable `g`... im not sure what ur looking for...

Comment: Yes there is - it's mentioned in paintComponent

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the paintComponent(Graphics g) method in the class that extends the JPanel, i.e. your Test class. You wrote a paintComponent method in a class DDA2 but that does nothing.

In the paintComponent method you can then call:

```
    g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Vincent says, it looks like you want to have the `fillRect` taking place in your `licz` method. No problem. Simply call your `licz` method from the `paintComponent` method. (It's easiest to do this if your method is defined in the same class as the `paintComponent` method, by the way.)